# Tell wordpress to save and organize images into folders?

Tags: wordpress, images, database, amazon-s3, storage

wordpress
Is there a way to tell wordpress to sort our images and data in folders...
So for example I am creating a bunch of posts about cars and is it not nice to have wordpress store those images from that series into a folder called "cars" on S3?

Is that possible? Is that good or bad?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Yes, it is a good idea (for all sorts of reasons, from simplifying management to SEO).

There's a load of plugins designed to do just that. Just search for "wordpress media library management plugin" in your preferred search engine and pick one that suits your specific needs.

Comment: Does that change the url of the images though?

Comment: That depends which plugin you get. Some do create a "physical" file structure with subdirectories.

Comment: Do you recommend these with physical file structure? And can this cause problems when migrating the website?